# Has anybody successfully did hyper-ledger fabric network setup on Minikube environment?

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric

Are there any examples for creating a blockchain network on top of minikube environment?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following repositories where you can find **helm charts** which should facilitate the whole deployment process:

- https://github.com/hyfen-nl/PIVT
- https://github.com/splunk/hyperledger-fabric-k8s

Note that they require **helm 2.11 and 2.16** or newer installed in your kubernetes cluster.